# filtering redis monitor lpush

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I have a box that has a lot of redis stuff going on. I converted my code from writing to a channel to doing a lpush. To see how my output I used redis-cli's `monitor` command. Is there a way to filter the monitor to command to show only the lpush channel I'm interested in. Theres a lot on the server so I can't catch my output.

For reference I use to do redis-cli subscribe channelname. But this does not work for lpush

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd grep it:

```
$ redis-cli monitor | grep -i "lpush"
```

Comment: It's worth to mention that it may be `rpush` also. For example, `redis.call('rpush', KEYS[1], ARGV[1])`. Please check the following: https://redis.io/docs/data-types/lists/#basic-commands